# v8 NewInstance memory leak

Tags: javascript, c++, embedded-v8

I have a problem with v8. I am creating object with NewInstance from Object Template. This function is being called every frame, and I have such code (see below), where GC does not collect objects from returned array and therefore I have memory leak

```
Events.on("frame", () => { let objs = Test.getAllObjects(); });
```

Test.getAllObjects returns array of objects created with NewInstance
I can't figure out why objects returned by this function are still alive

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. If you have such problem - remember to firstly save your object template to Persistent and then get it from it